# Tab Layout fix only 5 tabs and other make scrollable?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have implemented tabLayout with viewPager. My requirement is to fix only 5 tabs on the device width and if more than 5, then the tabs from 6th should be scrollable.

I tried using tabModes as fixed and tabMode as scrollable, i also tried manipulating the width, but no luck.

The PagerTabStrip width should be modified along with it.

Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `PagerTabStrip`

Comment: yes pagerTabStrip width should also gets modifies, thankx for noticing.

Comment: You should use TabLayout instead..It is native and better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)**

> PagerTabStrip is an interactive indicator of the current, next, and
>   previous pages of a ViewPager. It is intended to be used as a child
>   view of a ViewPager widget in your XML layout.

Please check Demo **[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)** .

Comment: okay, but i am not sure if it will satisfy my requirement, i have a total of 20 items, when user lands on the screen i only want to show 5 items, after 5 items the other items should be scrollable. For, now if it set it to tabMode as scrollable, is setting to 4 items as per the device width. and after 4 it is scrollable, and if i set tabMode to be fixed, it accomodating all datas without scroll.

Comment: Is it possible to make only 5 or 6 tabs fit in every device, for tab layout for scrollView. By default, it calculates the width of each tab dynamically for scrollView.

Comment: You can try with `Display Metric ` Rule . But don't know is it helpful or not

Answer (score -1):

Download both files copy it to your project

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

and then try some thing like this

```
 ViewPager pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//your pager id
  SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tab);
        TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter=new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
```

and your xml file would be something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.example.SlidingTabLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tab">



    </com.example.SlidingTabLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are using slidingTab layout here, which evenly distributes the item. I am using TabLayout and my requirement is diffn, please read my question again, don't answer it, just because you want to.